# TypeError: Can not extend/implement [class org.apache.solr.request.SolrQueryRequestBase] because of java.security. accessing SolrQueryRequest req

Tags: solr

SOLR 9.0
I am attempting to access the req variable as described here:

https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/configuration-guide/script-update-processor.html#script-execution-context

However, in my response I get this error:

```
Unable to invoke function processAdd in script: test-script.js: TypeError: Can not extend/implement [class org.apache.solr.request.SolrQueryRequestBase] because of java.security.
```

It states the error is on line 15 which is

```
some_param = req.getParams().get("commit")
```

This is right from the example in the documentation.

This seems like an incompatibility between SOLR and nashborn JavaScript processor.

Complete script here:

```
`/*
  This is a basic skeleton JavaScript update processor.

  In order for this to be executed, it must be properly wired into solrconfig.xml; by default it is commented out in
  the example solrconfig.xml and must be uncommented to be enabled.

  See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ScriptUpdateProcessor for more details.
*/

function processAdd(cmd) {


  doc = cmd.solrDoc;  // org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument
  childDocsPresent = doc.hasChildDocuments();
  some_param = req.getParams().get("commit")
  request = req.getJSON();
  // request.forEach((key, value) => {
  //   logger.warn(key, value)
  // });
  
  logger.warn("The value of child docs present is  " + childDocsPresent);
  

`// Set a field value:
//  doc.setField("foo_s", "whatever");

// Get a configuration parameter:
//  config_param = params.get('config_param');  // "params" only exists if processor configured with <lst name="params">

// Get a request parameter:
// some_param = req.getParams().get("some_param")

// Add a field of field names that match a pattern:
//   - Potentially useful to determine the fields/attributes represented in a result set, via faceting on field_name_ss
//  field_names = doc.getFieldNames().toArray();
//  for(i=0; i < field_names.length; i++) {
//    field_name = field_names[i];
//    if (/attr_.*/.test(field_name)) { doc.addField("attribute_ss", field_names[i]); }
//  }

}
function processDelete(cmd) {
  // no-op
}

function processMergeIndexes(cmd) {
  // no-op
}

function processCommit(cmd) {
  // no-op
}

function processRollback(cmd) {
  // no-op
}

function finish() {
  // no-op
}
```

I tried the script posted and excepted the request to run without throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

This error is the result of a new security setting in SOLR 9.0.
It was removed by editing the solr.in.sh
and adding the line:
SOLR_SECURITY_MANAGER_ENABLED=false